# Node server gives me undefined when I send data

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to send data to the server but when I log it gives me undefined even tho I can log it on the client. I think I'm missing something.

Thanks in Advance!

**Client**

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try{
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/send', {formData})
      console.log(response)
    } catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

**Server**

```
app.post('/send', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.send("ok")
})
```

Comment: Are you using `express.js` in the backend? It may help if you show how the server is being setup.

Comment: I posted an answer, hope it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
//client
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const config = {
      "headers":{
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
      }
    }
    const body = JSON.stringify({
      formData
    })
    try{
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/send', body, config)
      console.log(response)
    } catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
  
  // server 
  const express = require("express");
  const app = express();
  app.use(express.json()); // this is necessary

  app.post('/send', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.send("ok")
})
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I forgot to add " app.use(express.json()); " Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

remove the object property shorthand, use just `formData`:

```
 const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/send', formData)
```

Comment: He also needs a body parser since Express by default does not parse any POST body

Comment: @slebetman maybe it's out there, maybe not. we don't know anything about the server, as the OP didn't post the code, so I wouldn't speculate. that would be the next step, should the obvious problem with form data I pointed out not work..

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to set a header on the request

try adding config object as a 3rd argument

```
const config = {
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }


const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try{
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/send', 
      {formData}, config)
      console.log(response)
    } catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```